# Why doesn't Xcode have permission to view files?

Tags: ios, xcode, game-development, game-maker-studio-2

I tried to run my program on iOS. Build was successful but in the end I am getting a message that I don't have permission to view it. I tried to make Read/Write permission but it doesn't work. Any ides?

[image: Error message that I have got]

Comment: Is it any sort of system file path?

Comment: If I understand your question right. There are no sorting in my program, I just exported my GML studio 2 project to xcode to test in IO's.

Comment: @Bielskas did you ever find out how to sort out this issue? I am having the same problem